# Can't run Visual Studio Emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, windows-10, hyper-v

Formatted my computer with windows 8.1 pro and upgraded it to windows 10 pro, both x64.

Enabled Hyper-V on BIOS and on Windows Features, but no success. Disabled and enabled again, rebooted and nothing... Also reinstalled Visual Studio Emulator for Android and never works.

Always I get the error "**You have been added to the Hyper-V Administrators security group. Please sign out of your computer for the permissions to take effect**" when I try to run a android device.

What could I do for solve this?

**Screenshots below:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNXUn.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdrza.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install [**Intel HAXM**](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm) instead of enabling Hyper-V for the Android emulator. Only the Windows Phone emulators require Hyper-V, and HAXM and Hyper-V cannot be active simultaneously, which means that enabling one disables the other.

Also, dealing with emulators from Visual Studio itself is not recommended as it proved to be messy and unrealiable. Instead, you should manage the entire Android SDK and its emulators from the **Android SDK tools** standalone installer (not Android Studio). [Follow these instructions](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/) to install the Android SDK tools 24 standalone GUI and immediately update them to SDK tools 27, which includes the latest Android emulators.

Then, create the emulators from Android AVD Manager, and start your desired emulator. Whenever you deploy to emulator from Visual Studio, it will use the already running emulator, so you don't need to choose one from VS itself.

Comment: Indeed your answer is correct, I've tried this by the way, but that seemed to be a bug, which has been solved by reinstalling Windows 10 Pro on a clean install, as recommended I read somewhere. I'll mark as correct answer, because it's, but in last case, for those who are with the same problem, reinstall Windows 10 on a clean install in: https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/software-download/windows10